# Observe Socket-IO Messages

Tags: android, sockets, observable, rx-android, rx-java2

I am implementing a chat feature in my app using nkzawa sockets library. I have sent message to server using sockets and an endpoint (url string).

I have heard talk about RxJava and RxAndroid being the best way to observer data streams.

```
Observable.from(MyEndPoint).subscribe()
```

But I am having trouble passing a url parameter to observable.

Is it possible to create an observable to listen on my server's endpoint for new and existing messages. Please how do you go about retrieving socket messages in this way or another way, Thanks.

Edited as suggested:

Here's the code snippet I tried without Rx but not working:

```
private com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket(Constants.PUBLIC_CHAT_ENDPOINT);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Socket initialized like above and connected here:

```
mSocket.connect();
```

I am trying to get messages as demoed in the library docs but not working.

```
mSocket.on(Constants.SOCKET_GET_MESSAGE_EVENT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) args[0];
                        JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");

                        String type = dataObject.getString("type");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message is of type:\t" + type);

                        JSONObject contentObject = dataObject.getJSONObject("content");
                        String roomId = contentObject.getString("roomid");
                        String userId = contentObject.getString("userId");
                        String message = contentObject.getString("message");

                        Log.d(TAG, "Get Message is:\t" + message);
                        Log.d(TAG, "roomId:\t" + roomId);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Get userId is:\t" + userId);


                        TingTingUser otherUsers = new TingTingUser(userId, "Abhiram Labhani", "Unknown");
                        HomeMessage othersHomeMessages = new HomeMessage(message, otherUsers, System.currentTimeMillis());

                        List<HomeMessage> othersList = new ArrayList<>();
                        othersList.add(othersHomeMessages);

                        Log.d(TAG, "Other Messages size is:\t " + othersList.size());


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I want to implement the above code using RxJava but have no idea how to observe data from a dynamic, constantly updating endpoint as most of the docs and articles only use pre-defined data. Thanks.

Comment: For that you have to create your own socket io events like on_message, you dont need RxJava or RxAndroid to observe data streams

Comment: @ShripadJadhav, I have defined my own events for my chat room and stored the message in a url for that chat room. The problem is how to get all those messages and update the ui. I am using nkzawa socket io library for android. Thanks

Comment: Can you please add more code snippet

Comment: @ShripadJadhav, I have edited the question. Have a look. Thanks

Comment: Have you emmited any EVENT to get the all the messages? Your server must define an event to fetch the all the messages and you need to emit that event from the device end.